# Can I take "snapshots" for the IO Monad?

Tags: haskell, io, monads, arrows

I am currently writing an FRP library built on Arrows (namely, [timeless](https://github.com/carldong/timeless)). However, I encountered a problem:

If I wrap an `IO` action inside the arrow, (`Signal s IO a b` in this case, which is a Kleisli arrow), I would like to take a "snapshot" of the final returned value, instead of running the action every time. For example, I have an action involving reading a file and parsing into some data structure, and currently this action is running every frame of update. I tried a bit to make use of Haskell's lazy evaluation to prevent it from running again and again, but it did not work.

Conceptually, `Signal` is basically (but not exactly)

```
a -> IO (b, Signal)
```

Each update, the signal itself is replaced by the new signal. Now, I think if I feed an `IO` action with type `IO a` in (using Kleisli arrows), I can somehow replace the `Signal` with something else that holds the final result of the previous action. However, I cannot find a way to do it because I can't extract anything from `IO`, and simply replacing the signal to a constant one doesn't seem to stop the action from being reevaluated.

This is a minimal test program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

module Main where

import FRP.Timeless
import Debug.Trace

s1 :: (Monad m) => Signal s m a Int
s1 = mkConst $ trace "Signal 1" $ Just 5
s2 :: (Monad m) => Signal s m Int Int
s2 = arr $ trace "Signal 2" (+1)
s3 :: (Monad m) => Signal s m a ()
s3 = arr $ \_ -> ()

sc = mkKleisli_ $ \_ -> do
  putStrLn "SC"
  readFile "test.txt"
sp = mkKleisli_ putStrLn

box :: Signal s IO () ()
box = proc _ -> do
  file <- sc -< ()
  sp -< file
  returnA -< ()

box2 = proc _ -> do
  box -< ()

main = do
  runBox clockSession_ box2
```

Here, `sc` reads a file "Test.txt". It is evaluated every time. I would like to find a way to evaluate only once, and keep the value.

BTW, `unsafePerformIO` would probably work, but, as its name suggests, it is probably "unsafe", so I don't want to use it

Answer (score 1):

<del>OK, I think I get it work by adding this signal:</del>

```
onceSwitch = mkPureN $ (\_ -> (Just (), mkEmpty))
```

I generalized the switch to the following function (and added to `Prefab` of `timeless`):

```
occursFor :: b -> Int -> Signal s m a b
occursFor b n
    | n == 0 = mkEmpty
    | n > 0 = mkPureN $ \_ -> (Just b, occursFor b $ n-1)
    | otherwise = error "[ERROR] occursFor: Nothing occurs for less than zero times!"
```

<del>Whose output is `()` for the first time it is run, then inhibits, and this signal:</del>

```
onceIO = SGen $ f
  where
    f _ ma = return (ma, SArr $ const ma)
```

<del>Which becomes a constant after first run. Chaining an `IO` action like this:</del>

```
file <- onceIO <<< sc <<< () `occursFor` 1 -< ()
```

<del>seems to work intended. (Updated: now uses `occursFor`)</del>

After tweaking around, it looks like this. Notice that the API of `timeless` *will* change violently as I develop, but it is likely that the functions I use underneath will not change. Anyway, the same thing applies to `netwire`, which is the origin of `timeless`, with some minor changes. If you need to make some applications, use that for now.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows #-}

module Main where

import FRP.Timeless
import Debug.Trace

sc = mkKleisli_ $ \_ -> do
  putStrLn "SC"
  return "A"
sp = mkKleisli_ putStrLn

box :: Signal s IO () ()
box = proc _ -> do
  file <- snapOnce <<< sc <<< inhibitsAfter 1 -< ()
  sp -< file
  returnA -< ()

box2 = proc _ -> do
  box -< ()

main = do
  runBox clockSession_ box2
```